# Shopify Metafiled using img src to display pic

Tags: shopify, liquid

Is there any way to squeeze `<img src="//cdn.shopify...>` url in the following code or any other code:

```
{{ product.metafields.my_fields.file | img_tag }}
```

Trying to save the effort of having to reupload all images in shopify files metafield.
All images are already available on shopify CDN.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not easy to answer. First off, it almost begs questions. Like, if your images are already present and available on the CDN, why are you even having trouble rendering them? If your images are already present on the CDN, why would you go to the considerable trouble to store references to them as Metafield resources? It seems to me, that the answer here is for you to not use Metafields, and simply render images when and where needed, since they are already present on the CDN, ie) present in the store, and available to Liquid.

Comment: The store is a clothing store with several different size charts. Just trying to display size charts on their respective products (over 1000s of products). Manually uploading a file and then attaching it manually using meta-field is not a viable solution as the product count is too high.  There's gotta be a way to use  <img src ..> in {{ product.metafields.my_fields.file | img_tag }} or can you propose another solution

Comment: You have a finite number of size charts. Therefore, write a snippet to include in your product templete. Sniff the product for a tag. The tag tells you what sizing chart to show. Keep it simple.

Comment: are you able to provide a sample. I am just starting out with shopify and programming.